# Hybrid Mbr/GPT disc

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I am doing some playing around and have realized through research that the next task or thing to try is a hybrid MBR/GPT Hard drive.  I have read around and know that it is possible and doable.  Example most often cited are macs and bootcamp. However I have no interest in that scenario.  I am not worried about losing data.  I have certain programs that cannot use GPT and only use an MBR disc this is why I want to create a hybrid disc.  I have read it is doable from within Linux, but I am a basic noob with Linux and have a basic understanding only. If someone could walk me through the procure to create or at least attempt I would be grateful. I am hoping for the following scenario on a 4tb drive 2tb would go to mbr formatted fat32  the rest possibly gpt whatever filesystem was convenient.   Just as an FYI no OS is going on the drive just data.  I can get more specific if people would like. I have used mint Linux but would need program to use and total newbie instructions also FYI this is an external 4tb drive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `cgdisk`, and `sgdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) software, which can do what you want; ***HOWEVER,*** before proceeding, know that I ***STRONGLY*** recommend against creating hybrid MBRs, as they're known, unless you have a compelling reason to do so. It's not clear to me that this is the case for you. You state your reason as:

> I have certain programs that cannot use GPT and only use an MBR disc this is why I want to create a hybrid disc.

With the exception of some low-level tools such as disk partitioning and data recovery tools, programs access disks at a much higher level than the partition table, and so don't care about the partition table type. Word processors, Web browsers, video players, compilers, and so on all operate on files, which operate at a much higher level of abstraction than the partition table. The partition table is read by the OS kernel (such as Linux or the Windows kernel), and everything else accesses the disk through the kernel. Thus, these other tools don't need to understand the partition table type. It would help if you specify what program(s) you believe require specific partition table types.

The usual reason to create a hybrid MBR is, as you say, to enable a Mac to dual-boot between macOS and an older BIOS-mode OS like Windows 7 or earlier. (Windows 7 can boot in EFI mode on UEFI-based PCs, but the last I heard, getting it to do so on a Mac was very tricky at best.) Some people who run Hackintosh setups (macOS on a PC) also use hybrid MBRs. On rare occasion, it might be used on UEFI-based PCs that dual-boot between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode OSes; but IMHO in most cases it would be better to set all OSes to boot in a single boot mode (BIOS or EFI).

That said, if you really do need to create a hybrid MBR, [my page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) provides some guidance. In brief:

1. Launch `gdisk` on the disk you want to hybridize.
2. Type `p` to view the partitions and verify you're operating on the correct disk.
3. Type `r` to enter the recovery & transformation menu.
4. Type `h` to create a hybrid MBR.
5. At the prompt, enter the numbers of the partitions you want to hybridize. (Use the partition list from when you typed `p` as a reference.)
6. `gdisk` will ask a series of questions about where to place the 0xEE partition, type codes, and so on. Answer them.
7. Type `o` (lowercase letter O) to view the hybrid MBR and verify that it's what you expect.
8. Type `w` to save your changes.
9. Verify that you want to proceed.

At this point, your disk should have a hybrid MBR. Note that your OS might or might not immediately register the change, depending on the OS and whether any partitions on the disk were mounted before you began.